# Calling Fragment from setTabListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have the same Fragment:

```
public class Movies extends Fragment {

    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movies_at_now, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);

        MovieAdapter adapter = new MovieAdapter(getActivity(), initData());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        return view;
    }

    private List<MovieItem> initData () {
        List<MovieItem> list = new ArrayList<MovieItem>();

        list.add(new MovieItem("M1");
        list.add(new MovieItem("M2");
        list.add(new MovieItem("M3");

        return list;
    }


}
```

How can I set this fragment as a tab's content using **setTabListener** in another class?

Thanks.

---

**UPD:**

**setTabListener** in Main activity:

```
tab.setTabListener(new MyTabListener());
```

**MyTabListener.java** source code:

```
public class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if( tab.getPosition() == 1) {
            Movies frag = new Movies();
            ft.replace(R.id.tmpListView, frag);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //ft.remove(frag);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    }
}
```

So, `frag` returns non-Fragment type. How to solve this problem?

Comment: `setTabListener-method` ?? can you post it?

Comment: post the code where you set your tab listener

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin , the post is updated.

Comment: what do you mean `returns non-Fragment type`???

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin , `error: incompatible types: Movies cannot be converted to Fragment`